# IE8 JQuery Form Submission

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form using the jQuery .submit() method. It works in every browser but IE8 standards mode, and of course this is the browser I have to support. Here is my code:

```
$("button.submit").on('click', function (){

    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
    {
        $("div.alerts").html("<h3 class='error'>You do not have sufficient permissions for this action</h3>").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
        return false;
    }
    var passed = true;
    $('.required').each(function(){
        console.log('validating required elements');
            if(!$(this).val() || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == '')
            {
                $("div.alerts").html("<h3 class='error'>Required Information is missing. Please enter the " + $(this).attr('name') + " field").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                $(this).on('keyup click', function(){$(this).css('background-color', '#fff');});
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red').focus();
                passed = false;
                return false;
            }
    });
    if(passed)
    {
        console.log('saving');
        $("form#editTemplate").submit();
    }
```

and here is the form:

```
<form id = 'edittemplate' ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" method = "POST" action ="somefile.php" >
    <ul>
        <span class='left'>
            <li>
                <label>Title</label>
                <span class='formElement'><input type='text' name='name' class='required' value = 'example'/></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Description</label>
                <span class='formElement'><input type='text' name='description' class='required' value = 'example' /></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <span class='formElement'><input type='text' class='required' name='templatesubject' value = 'example'/></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>CID</label>
                <span class='formElement'><input type='text' name='c2ktemplateid' value = '509' readonly="readonly"/></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Attachments</label>
                <span class='formElement'><input type='file' name='attachment' id='attachment' /></span>
            </li>
        </span>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I do have multiple forms on the page that are hidden (for jquery modal forms). I know that the enter button won't work, but you can't even click on the submit. In addition, if I watch the console, it does get all the way to "saving" the submit event just doesn't fire. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `<ul><span class='left'><li>` is this the actual markup? that's invalid and in IE8...i can't even imagine how that could look right. Also, why `form#editTemplate`? id's are supposed to be unique, no reason to tell it to search for an ID for that element type. Moreover....I don't even see `<button class="submit"/>` anywhere on your page...

Comment: I didn't provide all of the html on the page, that's why you don't see a button with the class of submit, but it does exist. in addition, changing spans to divs didn't help

Comment: it won't help your particular issue, but that is also incorrect, the correct markup is `<ul>` THEN `<li>` then `<span>` or `<div>` or whatever else you want, if you try `<ul>` then `<any other element besides an LI>` that is not valid.

Comment: The desired effect is to group the li's and float some to the left and some to the right

Comment: `<form id = 'edittemplate'>` .... `$("form#editTemplate").submit();`...capital T, lowercase t?